# Простой WYSIWYG редактор

Tags: wysiwyg, редактор

Нужен простой **кроссбраузерный** Wysiwyg редактор. Для небольшого сайта, чтобы редактировать статьи. С инструкцией по установке, желательно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой, на мой взгляд, редактор - [SPAW Editor](http://www.spaweditor.com/en/disp.php/en_index).

Comment: Это Вы называете самым простым? Тут либо что-то с простотой, либо со взглядом.

Answer (score 3):

Редакторов много. Что-то из них может вам подойти:

- [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
- [YUI Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)
- [Xinha](http://xinha.webfactional.com/)
- [HtmlBox](http://remiya.com/htmlbox/)
- [Lightweight RTE](http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/rich-text-editor-jquery.html)
- [jWYSIWYG](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg)
- [markItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)

Comment: Спасибо, HtmlBox то что нужно